# Know Who Lock the File in Commit Box in TSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I able to see who lock the file in the commit message box in tortoise svn. Because I have so many file to commit but i don't know what files are locked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the Commit dialog. Right-click your working copy, select Check for Modifications, then click Check Repository. This will show you all files in your WC that have locks from other people.